# Car will push start, but not start normally

Tags: starting, nissan, cold-start

I have a 2003 Nissan Sentra ser spec v. The car has new spark plugs and coils, battery, starter and camshaft and crank shaft position sensors. As stated, the car will crank but will not start. When having the car pushed it will start and the first little bit after turning the car off it will start right up but after cooling down the same problem occurs.

What could be the cause of that?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Does cranking the engine for longer let it start?  Or maybe giving it a little bit of gas while cranking?

Comment: Does it go if jump started/has a supplemental battery connected?

Comment: How old is the battery, and how old is the starter?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a fault with these same symptoms that was caused by a faulty ignition switch.  When the switch was turned to the start position, the ignition circuit was disconnected, hence the engine did not start.

When the engine is hot and it successfully restarts using the key, does the engine appear to start as the switch is turned back from the start position?  If so, this will back up the faulty switch theory.